# Groovy way to instantiate an interface in runtime?

Tags: groovy

Objective: to instantiate an interface in runtime, and then process any invocation on it. By "any" I mean even invocations of the methods has not been defined in the interface directly.

Design: I'm casting a `Map` to the desired type and then add some methods to its `metaClass`.

Result: this creature can successfully process undeclared methods, but it can't process the honestly declared ones - an UnsupportedOperationException is thrown.

Question: can I process the declared methods too?

```
interface StackApi {
    void declaredMethod()
}

@Test
void reproduction() {
    StackApi api = [:].asType(StackApi)
    api.metaClass.declaredMethod = { Object[] args -> println "declaredMethod!"}
    api.metaClass.undeclaredMethod = { Object[] args -> println "undeclaredMethod!"}
    api.undeclaredMethod() // invoked ok
    api.declaredMethod() // UnsupportedOperationException thrown
}
```

UPD. I managed to fix that partially (see below), but it works for only pre-known method names. May be there is a way to setup a single handler that accepts absolutely all invocations?

```
@Test
void partial_success() {
    StackApi api = [
            declaredMethod: { Object[] args -> println "declaredMethod!"},
    ].asType(StackApi)
    api.metaClass.undeclaredMethod = { Object[] args -> println "undeclaredMethod!"}
    api.undeclaredMethod() // ok
    api.declaredMethod() // ok
}
```

P.S. casting to `StackApi` is important

Comment: Have you tried `api.metaClass.undeclaredMethod = { ...args -> println "undeclaredMethod!"}`

Comment: The last example works for me in the latest Groovy (3.0.2).

Comment: `def api = StackApi.class.declaredMethods.collectEntries{ [ (it.name): {Object ... arg-> println "not implemented" }]} as StackApi`